# ASP.NET Core systemd service hosted with NGINX slow first response time after update

Tags: services, nginx, systemd, asp.net, delay

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application DLL running on my CentOS instance as a systemd service

MyApp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp/bin/Release/net6.0/linux-x64/publish/MyApp.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=my app
User=myapp
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

When I update my application the flow goes (more or less) like this:

```
service MyApp stop
- remove "/var/www/myapp/*" contents -
- publish application -
- replace new published application in "/var/www/myapp/" -
service MyApp start
```

However, when I browse to my application the first time after the update (I even waited 5 minutes once) the first connection seems to be very slow, as if it is "waking up" my service  or establishing the reverse proxy or something like that, which causes the first user to think the application is "frozen"

This behaviour only occurs after an update, it does not happen on a regular basis

Could it be something NGINX or systemd related?

Any thoughts on what can cause this behaviour and how I could avoid / handle it?
Kind regards

Comment: What upstream URL is configured in Nginx, and what socket is the dotnet app listening on? Are they both on the same machine?

Comment: @user1686 yes they are both on the same machine, url is "www.myapp.com" (this linux instance) and it passes it on to localhost:7001 (where the .dll is listening to), no changes to A records or anything DNS related during the update

Comment: Try on your local PC (keep in mind it's probably much faster): is the behavior any different? // Warm-up requests to web applications are a thing, and for a reason.

Comment: @DanielB I did try this on a local VM (as I am running Windows and the instance is CentOS) with the same result